# Is it natural to use "But when"?

Tags: sentence-construction, adverbs

I wrote this sentence

> Suppose that a user wants to eliminate the navigation links from the page sidebar. She may employ the link density feature in a rule to distinguish this part. (**BUT** ?) When this rule is applied to the page, all such elements will be (are?) removed, regardless of their location in the page, even if they are inside the main content.

I feel if I use **but** I can make a contrast between two succeeding sentences. as something surprising happened. Is it natural?

Answer (score 1):

Of course its natural, there is also a meme that uses that:

"The Most Interesting Man In The World is an image macro series based on an advertising campaign for Dos Equis beer. The captions typically follow the phrasal template “I don’t always X, but when I do, I Y.”"

http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/the-most-interesting-man-in-the-world

Comment: I think you should provide the content of the link in your answer. (per advice of the moderators here)